# I can't post custom stories using own URL on FaceBook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post an activity using custom stories on facebook..

I have a stories: Vote an Item..
Action Types: Vote..
Object Types: Item..

When I try to use my own url:

```
 FB.api(
  '/me/ranker_testing:vote',
  'POST',
  {"item":"http://okxok.asia/ItemDetail/Lifestyle-36"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

It will pass an error:

```
   {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3502) Object at URL http://okxok.asia/ItemDetail/Lifestyle-36 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'item' requires an object of og:type 'product.item'. ",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 3502,
    "fbtrace_id": "BazVNO+qVfY"
  }
}
```

But if I use default sample url:

```
FB.api(
  '/me/ranker_testing:vote',
  'POST',
  {"item":"http://samples.ogp.me/612460332144487"},
  function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
  }
);
```

It will success, refer image below:

[image]

Any idea why this happen?
What does it means: **The property 'item' requires an object of og:type 'product.item'.**

Thank You!

Comment: You need to set the `og:type` meta tag in the HTML code of your object, and the value as to be `product.item`. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Comment: @CBroe: I have tried to set the og:type to product.item.. but the the error still exist..

Comment: Debug your item URL, and fix all possible errors/warnings it might show. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: @CBroe: I have already check, and there is an error: **fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app**. But I have already added the fb:app_id tag. You can check on: http://okxok.asia/ItemDetail/Lifestyle-36.

Comment: That document still doesn’t have an `og:type` meta tag.